# ASP.NET Url rewrite not functioning properly

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Well im trying a simple

i have a simple web service like page containing

```
public partial class WebApi : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static GetImageResult GetRandomImage()
    ...
```

i have added the following to "Global.asax.cs" (Application_BeginRequest)

```
string absolutePath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(1);

if (absolutePath.StartsWith("WebApi/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Context.RewritePath("/WebApi.aspx/" + absolutePath.Substring(7));
}
```

but asp.net seems to have a problem with this the function is never called and javascript just reports "Method Not Allowed".

Is there some thing more i have to do to make this work?

Comment: You should take a look at the IIS UrlWrite Module. http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Comment: @Phill what is the difference between IIS Rewrite and ASP.net Rewrite and how would it solve my problem?

Comment: Because the IIS Rewrite Module will rewrite the URL before it gets to your application (.NET or PHP or anything) and will be much easier to setup and test in the GUI window which allows you to write a regular expression and sample url to test with.

Comment: Also now that .NET has Routing, and IIS has UrlRewrite Module, any custom rewriting functionality like you're trying to do... is pretty much void now. :( (it really is easy with IIS Rewrite Module)

Comment: @Phill ok ill try it when i get home!

Comment: @Phill it worked only down side is that i guess ill have to use iis when i debug, any way thanks post it as a answer and ill mark it as one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using IIS Url Rewrite Module rather than trying to roll your own. It will intercept the request before it gets to your application, and provides a GUI for you to write and test the regular expression against your urls.

http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite